# How do I access a file in Amazon S3 private bucket through simple URL?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have video file in S3 private bucket. And I want my application to open it in a video player by using a URL.

I think I saw a url in this format: `http://s3.amazonAWS.com/bucket/filename?signedstring`

where `signedstring` is a query with params `AWSAccessKeyId, Expires, Signature`

I have access key ID. But when I tried to read up on how to sign it - the things make little sense to me..

**Is this approach the simplest one ?**

I dont really need everything. I just need to be able to construct a URL and open video file.

**Is there a simple C# code to sign the query ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the AWS SDK for .NET (http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/) to create pre-signed URLs for your S3 Objects. Here's an example that will create a pre-signed url that is valid for 15 minutes:

```
var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(awsKeyId, awsSecretKey);
var url = s3Client.GetPreSignedUrl( new GetPreSignedUrlRequest {
    BucketName = bucket,
    Key = objectKey,
    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(15) 
});
```

There are additional examples in the [documentation for `GetPreSignedUrl()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/items/M_Amazon_S3_AmazonS3Client_GetPreSignedURL_Amazon_S3_Model_GetPreSignedUrlRequest__NET4_5.html).

Comment: The SDK also installs a lot of useful features to the Visual Studio.. For example - I could create pre-signed URL from a dialog and just copy paste - for testing purposes